# When to use emit and broadcast in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events

I have been playing with Angular for 1 month and every time I thought It would make sense to use emit and broadcast to communicate between different parts of the framework I found articles stating that we should avoid them if we can (for instance: http://seanhess.github.io/2013/10/14/angularjs-directive-design.html)

So far I focused on communication between directive and controller, and between controller and service:

- Directive <--> Controller: To call controller's methods from directive I use isolated scope and callback. In the other direction I use state variables in the controller that are watched in the directive and when modified trigger directive's methods .
- Controller <--> Service: same mechanism. I use service's methods directly in my controller (this is the classic usage of service) and state variables in the service that are watched in the controller.

My question is straightforward: could you give me examples and explanations when emit and broadcast are relevant ?

Answer (score 1):

When you need to send a message or a request from inner scope to outer scope you can use $emit and when you want to do same from outer scope to inner scope we use $broadcast.

Comment: I get this point, my question is rather when is it relevant to use messaging system instead of "direct communication" (using callbacks and calls as described above) ?

Comment: This is used only when direct communication is not possible, You can use callbacks only when the functions are in same scope not outside the scope.